# Passing a function as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a `handleDelete` function as a prop. In the child component I want to delete the specific Todo from the list by clicking on the button there.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        key:0,
        temp:'',
        list:[]
    }
}

handleList = () => {

    let { key,temp } = this.state;
    if (temp.length > 0 ) {
        let list = [...this.state.list];
        list.push(<Todo 
            delete = {()=>{this.handleDelete(key)}}
            text = {temp} 
            key = {key}/>);
        this.setState({
            list:list,
            key: this.state.key+1
        });
    }
}

handleDelete = (index) =>{
    let list = [...this.state.list];
    list.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({list});
    console.log('list',list.length);

}


render() {

    return(
        <div className = 'global'>

           <button onClick={() => {this.handleList()}
            }>Add-New</button>
           <button onClick={() => {this.handleDelete(key)}
            }>delete</button>
            <input 
                onChange = {
                    (e)=>{this.setState({
                        temp: e.target.value
                    })}
                }
                type = 'text' 
                placeholder = 'Enter New Todo!'/>
            <hr/>
     </div>
```

Todo component

```
const Todo = (props) =>{
    return(
        <li>
            <h3>{props.text}</h3>
            <button onClick = {()=>
                props.delete
            }>Del</button>
            <hr/>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `handleDelete` function does what it says: what you're doing looks like it should work, except that you're not actually *calling* the function in `<Todo>`.

**Your original handler in `<Todo>` invokes an arrow function that returns the passed in function, but fails to invoke the passed in function itself.**

Change your component to *invoke* the function that's passed in the props:

```
const Todo = (props) =>{
    return(
        <li>
            <h3>{props.text}</h3>
            <button onClick = {() => props.delete()}>Del</button>
            <hr/>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Per the comments on my original answer, this could be further simplified:

```
const Todo = (props) =>{
    return(
        <li>
            <h3>{props.text}</h3>
            <button onClick = {props.delete}>Del</button>
            <hr/>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: The arrow function is unnecessary. It could be just `props.delete`

Comment: Just the reference. Using `props.delete()` would call the function during `render`

Comment: Now that you've removed the arrow function, you forgot to remove the call of delete.  Remove the `()`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: thanks, everyone. still problem though. I can delete every element of the list except the last one.any one why is that

Comment: @Sid can I suggest that you create a new question instead of asking on this one?  Perhaps there's an issue with the way you're handling your keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass handleDelete() as a property, you can do it like this.

add Todo inside the return of your main component (component with states). So under the div className = 'global', you can put:

```
<Todo handleDelte={this.handleDelete} />
```

then on your Todo component, to use it:

```
const Todo = ({handleDelete}) => {content}
```

Also, be sure that Todo component is imported in your main component (component with states)